# Передать объект из фрагмента в другой фрагмент

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

При нажатии на какую либо "заметку" в `RecyclerView` в первом фрагменте, нужно передать эту "заметку" в другой фрагмент, где можно будут её отредактировать. При моем коде во втором фрагменте в bundle приходит null. Прошу, помогите.

Слушатель нажатий в первом фрагменте:

```
adapter.setOnNoteClickListener(new NotesAdapter.OnNoteClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onNoteClick(Note note) {
        presenter.onNoteClicked(note);
        Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.dest_create_note);
        }
    });
```

Код метода вызываемого в слушателе первого фрагмента:

```
@Override
public void onNoteClicked(Note note) {
    CreateNoteFragment fragment = new CreateNoteFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable("Note", note);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
}
```

Код на получение и установку полученных данных объекта во втором фрагменте:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        note = bundle.getParcelable("Note");
    }
    if (note != null) {
        editTextTitle.setText(note.getTitle());
        editTextDescription.setText(note.getDescription());
            textViewDate.setText(String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.date_of_update), presenter.date()));
    }
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_note, container, false);
}
```

Реализация `Parcelable` в `Model`:

```
@Entity(tableName = "notes")
public class Note implements Parcelable {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String date;

    public Note(String title, String description, String date) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Ignore
    public Note ()  {
    }

    protected Note(Parcel in) {
        this.id = in.readInt();
        this.title = in.readString();
        this.description = in.readString();
        this.date = in.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(this.id);
        dest.writeString(this.title);
        dest.writeString(this.description);
        dest.writeString(this.date);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static final Creator<Note> CREATOR = new Creator<Note>() {
        @Override
        public Note createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Note(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Note[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Note[size];
        }
    };

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько я понял ваш код - вы используете `NavigationComponents`. Механика создания фрагментов в нем отличается от стандартной.

Если вы посмотрите на метод `Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate();` то увидите следующее.

```
/**
     * Navigate to a destination from the current navigation graph. This supports both navigating
     * via an {@link NavDestination#getAction(int) action} and directly navigating to a destination.
     *
     * @param resId an {@link NavDestination#getAction(int) action} id or a destination id to
     *              navigate to
     * @param args arguments to pass to the destination
     */
    public void navigate(@IdRes int resId, @Nullable Bundle args) {
        navigate(resId, args, null);
    }
```

Соответственно если вы хотите передать какие-то аргументы в создаваемый фрагмент вам необходимо создавать свой `Bundle` и класть его вторым параметром в метод `navigate()`.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle()
bundle.putParcelable(ARG_NOTE, note)
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(resId, bundle)
```